# Align inner div to center If there are two inner divs

Tags: css

[image]My code is below. Here I'm trying to align 'Header - 1 div' to center. But its not align properly.

```
<div style="width:100%;background-color:black;">
 <div style="color:red;width:80%;display:inline-block;float:left;text-align:center;">Header 1</div>
 <div style="color:yellow;width:20%;display:inline-block;">Header 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want basically...

Comment: @AnilKumarRam Hi , I only want to align 'header-1 div' to center of the outer div & 'header-2 div' needs to align right.

Comment: @AnilKumarRam, as you can see in image 'header-1' is not properly center. can you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<div style="width:100%;background-color:black;text-align:center;overflow:auto;">
 <div style="color:red;width:80%;display:inline-block;float:left;padding-left:20%;box-sizing:border-box;">Header 1</div>
 <div style="color:yellow;width:20%;display:inline-block;float:left;">Header 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is not working..? Try using run the code and see.

Comment: check now. Now it should be fine

Comment: It works. Can you please let me know Is it work for responsive design ?

Comment: yes it is working. It always working according to the device width and adapt according to the width. But you need to check with your media queries. As an example if you have media query for mobile devices and assume it as 480 max-width. How you going to show those DIVs in that size means 100% width each like. If it so, you need to change your styles to adapt 100% width. Other wise this way is fine.  If you are coding for responsive site don't use inline CSS. Use external CSS always.